# Check if Model has specific Spatie Tag

Tags: laravel, tags, laravel-8, laravel-tags

I'm using Spatie Tags and I have attached a few location tags to the user model. Now I want to see if the users is tagged to a location. Perhaps I can use the Laravel 'contains' function from collections? Things are complicated by the fact that Spatie stores the tags as json data with language.

I tried:

```
$user->tags->contains('Midtown')
```

but I get false even though the user has the tag:
{
"en": "Midtown"
}

There must be a built in way to check this but I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

Comment: you can do the following.  $user->tags()->containing('Midtown')->get();

Comment: And no any shorthand methods?